# Are there any known algorithms for finding a minimum locating set of an arbitrary connected graph?

Tags: python, algorithm, graph-theory

Given a connected graph G, and some subset of vertices of G (call it W={v_1, v_2, ..., v_n}), we say that for a particular vertex u of G the locating code of v with respect to W is the vector [d(u, v_1), d(u, v_2), ..., d(u, v_n)]. If every vertex of G has a unique locating code with respect to W, then we call W a locating set. If W is a locating set with the smallest possible number of vertices, then W is called a minimum locating set.

I tried writing a python program to solve this but I am *awful* at programming and the solution I came up with took forever even with relatively small graphs (like around 10 vertices). If any of you know a quick algorithm for this and could give some example code, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: This is called the [metric dimension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_dimension_(graph_theory)) and is NP-hard to compute, even for relatively simple graph classes (like bipartite, or bounded-degree planar). This question is probably better suited for the [computer science](https://cs.stackexchange.com/) or theoretical computer science site, as you'll get better information about state of the art algorithms there.